# ssh is picking up other keys

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

ssh utility is adding keys and doing stuff with known_hosts, and I get this error:

```
ubuntu@${addr}: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ssh-add -D
ssh -vvv -i 'my.pem' "ubuntu@${addr}"
```

and the output looks like this:

```
All identities removed.
Identity added: my.pem (/foo/bar/my.pem)
OpenSSH_9.4p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname addr is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to addr [addr] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /foo/bar.pem type 0
debug1: identity file /foo/bar/my.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to addr:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from addr
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:0HidS+549zMllwPBBwxHHsEVB+Cn0ry74BqoydNQ1MQ
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from addr
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'addr' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.i9j3Ib1jTd/Listeners'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /foo/bar/my.pem RSA SHA256:u78aFvgATWSytg6G79rGpglA2b38pD7briq9Oi0Q1gs explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /foo/bar/my.pem RSA SHA256:u78aFvgATWSytg6G79rGpglA2b38pD7briq9Oi0Q1gs explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ubuntu@addr: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Is the public key on the server? Is `my.pem` a secret key? It has an unusual name for an SSH key file.  Do you have a `~/.ssh/config` file? If so, what does it contain?

Comment: yeah, the pub key is in authorized_keys on the remote. I will add an answer - I guess only insight is for users to check to make sure if authorized_keys is formatted properly. Would it be too much to ask for the utility to check the formmating? Should give a parse error. KMN

Comment: Who should the parse error be reported to? One could certainly _not_ pass it to the unauthenticated external user as that would be divulging information that the user should not have access to.

Comment: Isn't `${addr}` meant to be a web address or IP? But it shows up in the error message you have included at the top, as if it where enclosed in single quotes, i.e.  `ssh -vvv -i 'my.pem' 'ubuntu@${addr}'`. If `$addr` was empty, we should see an error `ubuntu@: Permission denied (publickey).` . (only masochists are fans of the `ssh` utility family (-;! )

Comment: yes we agree, my answer covers what I experienced, at least

Answer (score 0):

So I am not a big fan of the ssh utility frankly, and I can't really remember how I fixed it because I threw the whole kitchen sink at it, but this works:

```
    chmod 600 my.pem
    chmod 600 my.pem.pub
    
    ssh-add -D
    
    ssh -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \ 
       -i '${pemPath}.pem' "ubuntu@${addr}"
```

oh yeah, the other problem I had was I had this in authorized_keys

```
ssh-rsa ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA....(omitted)...a0b51 me@myhost
```

I had two "ssh-rsa ssh-rsa ..." in the file, it just needs one (clearly), so make sure that file is not malformatted.

Should be like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA....(omitted)...a0b51 me@myhost
```

Comment: key idea is to make sure you check the formatting in authorized_keys on the remote...